# How to preserve order of a DataFrame when writing it as CSV with partitioning by columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I sort the rows of a `DataFrame` and write it out to disk like so:

```
df.
  orderBy("foo").
  write.
  partitionBy("bar", "moo").
  option("compression", "gzip").
  csv(outDir)
```

When I look into the generated .csv.gz files, their order is not preserved. Is this the way Spark does this? Is there a way to preserve order when writing a DF to disk with a partitioning?

Edit: To be more precise: Not the order of the CSVs is off, but the order inside them. Let's say I have it like the following after `df.orderBy` (for simplicity, I now only partition by one column):

```
foo | bar | baz
===============
  1 |   1 |   1
  1 |   2 |   2
  1 |   1 |   3
  2 |   3 |   4
  2 |   1 |   5
  3 |   2 |   6
  3 |   3 |   7
  4 |   2 |   9
  4 |   1 |  10
```

I expect it to be like this, e.g. for files in folder `bar=1`:

part-00000-NNN.csv.gz:

```
1,1
1,3
2,5
```

part-00001-NNN.csv.gz:

```
3,8
4,10
```

But what it is like:

part-00000-NNN.csv.gz:

```
1,1
2,5
1,3
```

part-00001-NNN.csv.gz:

```
4,10
3,8
```

Comment: Which spark version u are using

Comment: I am using 2.3.1

Comment: I am going to try this this weekend as well. There is "Bucketing". But normally upon read you will get a split and would need to repartition always to be sure. Hashing vs RangeBy ... ? Interesting stuff causing confusion and then Hive compatible in the past.

Comment: The result of the task is used in a .net application that reads the data back in and puts it into an MSSQL database using FILESTREAM columns (this is the requirement by a third party). Since each folder is read one after the other and there are never more than 600000 entries in all CSVs combined anyway, I currently read everything into memory and re-sort it. For this special case it's tolerable but it would be nice to know more about what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while but I witnessed this again. I finally came across a workaround.

Suppose, your schema is like:

- time: bigint
- channel: string
- value: double

If you do:

```
df.sortBy("time").write.partitionBy("channel").csv("hdfs:///foo")
```

the timestamps in the individual `part-*` files get tossed around.

If you do:

```
df.sortBy("channel", "time").write.partitionBy("channel").csv("hdfs:///foo")
```

the order is correct.

I think it has to do with shuffling. So, as a workaround, I am now sorting by the columns I want my data to be partitioned by first, then by the column I want to have it sorted in the individual files.